# Haskell cannot compile

Tags: haskell, types, polynomials

As usuall I am suffering the problem, that on paper everything should work, but the compiler gives an error which I just cannot understand.

```
data Polynom = Polynom[Double] 
           deriving Show



calcPolynom :: Double -> Polynom -> Double
calcPolynom _ [] = 0.0
calcPolynom _ Polynom [] = 0.0
calcPolynom n Polynom[h:ts] = h + n* Polynom[ts]
```

giving the error "Constructor `Polynom' should have 1 argument, but has been given none".
But I did and neet it to be defined also for empty polynoms.

Can anybody help? I am really new to haskell and i really apreciate any sort of help :)

Additional information: I want polynomes to be a list of Doubles i.e. 
    2x³ - 1.4x² + 2.5 = [2.5,0,-1.4,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some parentheses and to fix your pattern matching:

```
calcPolynom _ (Polynom []) = 0.0
calcPolynom n (Polynom (h:ts)) = h + n * ???
```

I left a blank for you to fill in at the `???`, you'll have to figure out what should go there instead of what you have right now.  The reason why is that you can't multiply a value of type `Double` with a value of type `Polynom`, but you could write this recursively (I'm assuming that was your original intention).

When you have code like

```
calcPolynom n Polynom [h:ts] = ...
```

The compiler sees that `calcPolynom` has 3 arguments and `Polynom` has none, you use parentheses for grouping.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Of course I meant to write recursion, figured it out quickly

Answer (score 1):

try

```
calcPolynom _ (Polynom []) = 0.0
calcPolynom n (Polynom (h:ts)) = h + n * calcPolynom n (Polynom ts)
```

When you try to pattern-match a constructor, you must enclose it in parenthesis. This not only applies to you Polynom data type, but also to lists. `[h:ts]` does not something different than you expect, it matches against a list of lists (`[[?]]`)with only one element (i.e. list). Finally, you have to recurse the function, not the data type.